# Preserving beamer's inner theme when displaying an indented table of contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, themes

Following up on ["Beamer - How to get subsection indent with a numbered TOC?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371580/beamer-how-to-get-subsection-indent-with-a-numbered-toc/371613?noredirect=1#comment1736542_371613), is there a way to indent items in a table of contents in such a way that the chosen inner theme applies to the TOC as well?

The following example successfully modifies the indentation of TOC items, but fails to apply the chosen theme to the numbering (see the `enumerate` environment for a comparison):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\leavevmode\leftskip=3.2em\rlap{\hskip-2em\inserttocsectionnumber}\inserttocsection\par}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{One}
\section{Two}
\section{Three}

\begin{frame}
    Chosen Few
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item One
        \item Two
        \item Three
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the templates `\defbeamertemplate{section in toc}{circle}` and `\defbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{circle}` from [`beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/main/base/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty) as starting point and change the leftskip as you like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}
{\leavevmode\leftskip=4ex% Change value here, origionally 2ex
  \llap{%
    \usebeamerfont*{section number projected}%
    \usebeamercolor{section number projected}%
    \begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{0ex}{1ex}{2ex}
      \color{bg}
      \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{.75ex}}{1.2ex}
      \pgfusepath{fill}
      \pgftext[base]{\color{fg}\inserttocsectionnumber}
    \end{pgfpicture}\kern1.25ex%
  }%
  \inserttocsection\par}

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}
{\leavevmode\leftskip=2em\inserttocsubsection\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{One}
\section{Two}
\section{Three}

\begin{frame}
    Chosen Few
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item One
        \item Two
        \item Three
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works in my case, but is there any hope for a more generic solution? Meaning: automatically detecting which inner theme has been used and inserting whatever's needed into `setbeamertemplate`, rather than needing to copy / paste styles?

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre Knowing the innner theme does not necessarily mean you know how a particular template looks like. The user could manually choose another style for the toc

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre In general, you can test if a particular theme is loaded with `\IfPackageLoadedTF{beamerinnerthemecircles}{true}{false}`, however this does not mean that a particular toc style is used. Other theme or the user can overwrite the toc style.